# A question on self-adjoint operator on Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

On page 348 of Infinite Dimensional Dynamical Systems in Mechanics and Physics by Roger Temam, there is something I don't understand. I abstracted the question as follow:
Let $T:H \rightarrow H$ be a bounded self-adjoint operator on Hilbert space $H$. If $T$ is nonnegative and have bounded inverse $T^{-1}$ then why
$$
\inf_{\| \phi \|=1} \langle T\phi , \phi \rangle >0.
$$
is valid?

I found a similar question here [Bounded Self-adjoint Operator on Hilbert Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582063/bounded-self-adjoint-operator-on-hilbert-space), however it only provide answer when $T$ is positive, is it true for nonnegative operator as well?

Comment: Yes, actually every invertible nonnegative operator is positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $m:=\inf_{\| \phi \|=1} \langle T\phi , \phi \rangle $ and $M:=\sup_{\| \phi \|=1} \langle T\phi , \phi \rangle $.

It is well known that for the spectrum of $T$ we have

$$ \sigma(T) \subseteq [m,M].$$

Suppose that that $m=0$, then $0 \in \sigma(T),$ a contradiction, since $T$ has a bounded inverse.